# SQL query for combinations without repetition

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I need a function that can generate all possible combinations of a given set of n values. For each combination, the function should also generate all combinations of length k, where k ranges from 1 to n.

For example, if the input is a table with three values in one column, then the function should generate all possible combinations of the three values, as well as all possible combinations of length 1, 2, and 3.

Example:
Input: table with values in one column in multiple rows

```
Value  (nvarchar(500))
------
Ann
John
Mark
```

Output#1: table with values concatenated in one column

```
    Ann
    John
    Mark
    Ann,John
    John,Mark
    Ann,Mark
    Ann,John,Mark
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For relatively small values of `n` (20 in this example), you can use a method that exploits the fact that the natural integers are combinations of bits.

### T-SQL Solution

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Sample AS TABLE 
(
    item_id     tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    item        nvarchar(500) NOT NULL,
    bit_value   AS 
                CONVERT
                (
                    integer, 
                    POWER(2, item_id - 1)
                )
                PERSISTED UNIQUE CLUSTERED
);    

INSERT @Sample
    (item)
VALUES
    (N'Ann'),
    (N'Bob'),
    (N'Charles'),
    (N'Darren'),
    (N'Eric'),
    (N'Fred'),
    (N'George'),
    (N'Harry'),
    (N'Ian'),
    (N'John'),
    (N'Keith'),
    (N'Larry'),
    (N'Mark'),
    (N'Nathan'),
    (N'Owen'),
    (N'Paul'),
    (N'Quentin'),
    (N'Ryan'),
    (N'Steve'),
    (N'Terry');
```

Solution:

```
-- Maximum integer we need
-- for all combinations of 'n' bits
DECLARE 
    @max integer = 
    POWER(2,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM @Sample AS s
        )
    ) - 1;

SELECT
    combination =
        STUFF
        (
            (
                -- Choose items where the bit is set
                -- and concatenate all matches
                SELECT ',' + s.item 
                FROM @Sample AS s
                WHERE
                    n.n & s.bit_value = s.bit_value
                ORDER BY
                    s.bit_value
                FOR XML 
                    PATH (''),
                    TYPE                    
            ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 1, 1, ''
        )
-- A standard numbers table
-- (single column, integers from 1 to 1048576, indexed)
FROM dbo.Numbers AS N
WHERE
    N.n BETWEEN 1 AND @max;
```

Output sample:

```
╔════════════════════════╗
║      combination       ║
╠════════════════════════╣
║ Ann                    ║
║ Bob                    ║
║ Ann,Bob                ║
║ Charles                ║
║ Ann,Charles            ║
║ Bob,Charles            ║
║ Ann,Bob,Charles        ║
║ Darren                 ║
║ Ann,Darren             ║
║ Bob,Darren             ║
║ Ann,Bob,Darren         ║
║ Charles,Darren         ║
║ Ann,Charles,Darren     ║
║ Bob,Charles,Darren     ║
║ Ann,Bob,Charles,Darren ║
║ ...                    ║
╚════════════════════════╝
```

Execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

It takes **41 seconds** to write the **1,048,576 combinations** to a variable on my laptop.  With forced parallelism, I was able to drop the execution time at `DOP 8` to 13 seconds.

If you need a Numbers table, this is a quick way to produce one:

```
SELECT TOP (1048576)
    n = ISNULL(CONVERT(integer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))), 0)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.columns AS c
CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c2
CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c3;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cuq
ON dbo.Numbers (n)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON);
```

### SQLCLR solution

A much more efficient implementation is possible in SQLCLR (SQL Server 2005 onward):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Demo]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 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
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Combinations
(
    @ElementsCSV nvarchar (4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
(
    Combination nvarchar (4000) NULL
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME Demo.UserDefinedFunctions.Permute;
```

Example usage:

```
SELECT 
    f.Combination
FROM dbo.Combinations('A,B,C,D') AS f;
```

Output:

```
╔═════════════╗
║ Combination ║
╠═════════════╣
║ A           ║
║ B           ║
║ A,B         ║
║ C           ║
║ A,C         ║
║ B,C         ║
║ A,B,C       ║
║ D           ║
║ A,D         ║
║ B,D         ║
║ A,B,D       ║
║ C,D         ║
║ A,C,D       ║
║ B,C,D       ║
║ A,B,C,D     ║
╚═════════════╝
```

Using the 20-element set from earlier:

```
DECLARE @Sample AS TABLE 
(
    item_id     tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    item        nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @Sample
    (item)
VALUES
    (N'Ann'),
    (N'Bob'),
    (N'Charles'),
    (N'Darren'),
    (N'Eric'),
    (N'Fred'),
    (N'George'),
    (N'Harry'),
    (N'Ian'),
    (N'John'),
    (N'Keith'),
    (N'Larry'),
    (N'Mark'),
    (N'Nathan'),
    (N'Owen'),
    (N'Paul'),
    (N'Quentin'),
    (N'Ryan'),
    (N'Steve'),
    (N'Terry');
```

SQLCLR solution:

```
-- Create CSV input
DECLARE 
    @Elements nvarchar(4000) =
        STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT ',' + s.item 
                FROM @Sample AS s
                ORDER BY
                    s.item_id
                FOR XML 
                    PATH (''),
                    TYPE                    
            ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 1, 1, ''
        );

DECLARE
    @bitbucket nvarchar(4000);

SELECT
    @bitbucket = combination
FROM dbo.Combinations(@Elements);
```

Execution time is **2.5 seconds** for the **1,048,576 combinations** on my laptop at `DOP 1`.

Creating the CSV input:

[image: CSV Input Plan]

Finding the combinations:

[image: SQLCLR Function Plan]

C# Source Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction
        (
        DataAccess=DataAccessKind.None, 
        SystemDataAccess=SystemDataAccessKind.None,
        FillRowMethodName="FillRow",
        TableDefinition="Permutation nvarchar(4000)"
        )
    ]
    public static IEnumerable Permute(string ElementsCSV)
    {
        // Split CSV
        string[] elements = ElementsCSV.Split(new char[] { ',' });

        // Highest integer needed
        int count = (int)Math.Pow(2, elements.Length) - 1;

        // Pre-computed array of 2^n values
        int[] powers = new int[elements.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < powers.Length; i++)
        {
            powers[i] = (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
        }

        // Test integers
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            // Reset output
            string s = string.Empty;

            // Test each bit that could be set
            for (int bit = 0; bit < powers.Length && i >= powers[bit]; bit++)
            {
                if ((i & powers[bit]) == powers[bit])
                {
                    // Add the element corresponding to the set bit
                    s += elements[bit] + ',';
                }
            }

            // Return a row via enumeration
            yield return s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
        }
    }

    // Called by SQL Server to fetch a row
    public static void FillRow(object o, out string Permutation)
    {
        Permutation = (string)o;
    }
}
```