# Join tables on a partial string match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

input: I have a table containing (any number of) user-supplied strings:

```
╔═══════╗
║ Value ║
╠═══════╣
║ To    ║
║ An    ║
╚═══════╝
```

And a table of user details:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID ║ UserName ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║     12 ║ Tom      ║
║    132 ║ Ann      ║
║     32 ║ Dina     ║
║      2 ║ Mark     ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

I need a query to return all records from the users table where `UserName` is a partial string match for any `Value` record in the input table.  Expected output in this case is:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID ║ UserName ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║     12 ║ Tom      ║
║    132 ║ Ann      ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @Users AS TABLE
(
    UserID      integer,
    UserName    nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT @Users
    (UserID, UserName)
VALUES
    (12, N'Tom'),
    (132, N'Ann'),
    (32, N'Dina'),
    (2, N'Mark');

DECLARE @Input AS TABLE
(
    Value    nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @Input (Value)
VALUES 
    (N'To'),
    (N'An');

SELECT * 
FROM @Users AS u 
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM @Input AS i 
        WHERE 
            u.UserName LIKE N'%' + i.Value + N'%'
    );
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID ║ UserName ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║     12 ║ Tom      ║
║    132 ║ Ann      ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the context from your previous question [SQL query for combinations without repitition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/sql-query-for-combinations-without-repetition) I think you are looking for a way to find combinations of users and include both the name and ID in the result set.  The following script demonstrates one way to achieve that:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Users AS TABLE
(
    UserID      integer,
    UserName    nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT @Users
    (UserID, UserName)
VALUES
    (12, N'Tom'),
    (132, N'Ann'),
    (32, N'Dina'),
    (2, N'Mark');
```

Load the source data into a table set up to make it easier to find combinations:

```
-- Working table to find combinations
DECLARE @Combination AS TABLE 
(
    item_id     tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    item        nvarchar(500) NOT NULL,
    item_value  integer NOT NULL,
    bit_value   AS 
                CONVERT
                (
                    integer, 
                    POWER(2, item_id - 1)
                )
                PERSISTED UNIQUE CLUSTERED
);    

-- Add user details to the working table
INSERT @Combination
    (item, item_value)
SELECT
    u.UserName,
    u.UserID
FROM @Users AS u;
```

Use the fact that the natural integers have a pattern of bits that match the combinations we want to find.  Determine the maximum integer value we need based on the number of items in the working table:

```
-- Maximum integer needed for combination bit values
DECLARE 
    @max integer = 
    POWER(2,
        (
            SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
            FROM @Combination
        )
    ) - 1;
```

Instead of concatenating group members using `FOR XML PATH`, list the combinations in rows with a `group_id` to identify each group:

```
-- Find combinations
SELECT
    group_id = N.n,
    c.item,
    c.item_value
FROM @Combination AS c
JOIN dbo.Numbers AS N ON
    n.n & c.bit_value = c.bit_value
WHERE
    N.n BETWEEN 1 AND @max
ORDER BY
    group_id;
```

Partial output:

```
╔══════════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ group_id ║ item ║ item_value ║
╠══════════╬══════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ Tom  ║         12 ║
║        2 ║ Ann  ║        132 ║
║        3 ║ Ann  ║        132 ║
║        3 ║ Tom  ║         12 ║
║        4 ║ Dina ║         32 ║
║        5 ║ Dina ║         32 ║
║        5 ║ Tom  ║         12 ║
║        6 ║ Ann  ║        132 ║
║        6 ║ Dina ║         32 ║
║        7 ║ Dina ║         32 ║
║        7 ║ Ann  ║        132 ║
║        7 ║ Tom  ║         12 ║
║        8 ║ Mark ║          2 ║
║        9 ║ Mark ║          2 ║
║        9 ║ Tom  ║         12 ║
╚══════════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific in what your trying to accomplish?  Thomas is right, it does seem like you want to take a procedural approach to something that can be done in a set based manner.

If your looking to get a set of results and then process them one at a time for an application, I strongly recommend doing that row based processing in your application.  SQL Server is designed to work with sets and not rows.

If your looking to have a procedure that returns the next row each time it is called. Again, I would suggest pulling the result set as a whole and processing the row based operations in your application code.

If you must do this in t-sql, then a cursor is what you would need.  I strongly recommend against this however since a cursor is a row by agonizing row operation and cursors are not very performant.